# How to control the item in 'RecyclerView' from other place in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

**UPDATED:**

I have download the data from FireStore & set adapter. Then shows the data in a RecyclerView.

My question is: If I want to delete any of the item in the RecyclerView from clicking the button which is outside the RecyclerView, how can I do?

Steps Example:

1. Get data from Firestore (Done)
   [example pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocA9e.png)
2. Click "Edit" button then the "Delete Icon button" show in every item
   [example pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jEs5.png)
3. Click "Delete Icon button" then the item is deleted.

**Layout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F8F8F8">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="edit"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <RecyclerView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the item from the list which you used in the adapter.
And then call `NotifyDataSetChanged()` function from which adapter will show the updated list.

If you post some code as well, its easier to guide ahead.

Comment: Hi okcomputer_kid,
Thanks for your fast reply, I have updated my question and it is to be more clear about my question.
The point is "How to control the item inside recycle view from the button which is outside the recycle view?" Such as change the item's property(visiability: GONE -> SHOW), and delete...

Answer (score 0):

in your onBindViewHolder

```
  holder.delete_button.setOnClickListener {
            AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Are you sure?")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to Delete this File ?")
                    .setPositiveButton("YES"
                    ) { dialog, which ->

                        deleteDb(post_id, position);//Call your methode here

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    .setNegativeButton("NO") { dialog, which ->
                        dialog.dismiss()
                    }
                    .create()
                    .show()

        }
```

---

```
 public void  deleteDb(String id,int position ) {
        DbOperations dbOperations =new DbOperations(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbOperations.getWritableDatabase();
        dbOperations.delete(db, id);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        audioItems.remove(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, audioItems.size);//this will update your View

    }
```

---

in your DbOperation class

```
    public void delete(SQLiteDatabase db, String id) {

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ProductContract.ProductEntry.ID, id);
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + ProductContract.ProductEntry.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
            + ProductContract.ProductEntry.ID + "= '" + id + "'");
    }
```

Comment: Hi Praveen,
Thanks for your fast reply, I have updated my question and it is to be more clear about my question.
The point is "How to control the item inside recycle view from the button which is outside the recycle view?" Such as change the item's property(visiability: GONE -> SHOW), and delete...

Answer (score 0):

On delete button click get the Clicked Object. Refer the Sample code

```
    Contact contact=arraylist.get(getAdapterPosition());
    deletecontact(contact);
```

This is the Method to delete that specific record from the database

```
    public void deletecontact(Contact contact) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete(Note.TABLE_NAME, Note.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.getId())});
            db.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create interface and implement the method for the same. On button click you need to call the method and override the method in your adapter class where you can change the visibility or do some operation as per your need.